# what should we do when we are not sure about flagging

Tags: discussion

I am  referring to following question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20423771/model-based-testing-tool-visual-studio-c-sharp

I think I should flag it, but I was not sure so I have 2 things to consider

1. I think the question should be flagged but not sure
2. If I wish to flag then in which option it should be flagged ..

   - Primarily Opinion based OR
   - Question asking for tools is out of scope of SO.

So what should we do?  Should we leave the question or should we flag any of the given flag option?

In short what should we do when we are not sure in which option the question should be flagged??

Answer (score 5):

Answer seems very simple, *do not* raise a flag which you are unsure about. Leave it as it is. Don't have to raise a flag necessarily.

For that particular question, I would and I just did flag it as

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it

Remember its not one man's job to clean up all the site. Its a community moderated site and someone else will come along and flag it if they are sure which flag to raise. Marshals don't raise checkered flag if they are not *absolutely* sure that its the last lap of the race.

Comment: then might be site will have lots of unwanted question

Comment: I would probably flag it as "too broad".

Comment: Its not one man's job to clean all the site. Its a community moderated site and someone else will come along and flag it if they are sure which flag to raise